# how to conditionally add where condition in linq

Tags: c#

I am using entity framework and i want to add a where condition only if the condition is met else i dont want that where to be executed which i want to do it in 1 query

```
Context.Test
                .Where(v => v.Valuation.ValuationPeriod.PeriodName == periodName && parameters.SelectedTemplateIds.Contains(v.TemplateTypeId) && fundBusinessIds.Contains(v.Fund.BusinessId))
                .Where(v =>  parameters.sortedList.Contains(v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.DealCode))
                .Where(v => wpGroup == null || v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.WPGroup == wpGroup)
                .Where(v => !myDeals || v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.UserPermission.Any(up => up.UserId == userId))
```

so in the above query

```
Where(v => parameters.sortedList.Contains(v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.DealCode))
```

I want to execute only if

```
parameters.sortedList.Count() > 0
```

else i dont want to include that where condition in the above query. So basically here i know we can do by seperating the query that is first get a list of values and then check this condition and if it matches then add a where on that list. But is it possible without doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The filter could be added contitionally as follows by using an intermediate assignment.

```
var result =  Context.Test.Where(v => v.Valuation.ValuationPeriod.PeriodName == periodName && parameters.SelectedTemplateIds.Contains(v.TemplateTypeId) && fundBusinessIds.Contains(v.Fund.BusinessId));

if (parameters.sortedList.Count() > 0)
{
    result = result.Where(v =>  parameters.sortedList.Contains(v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.DealCode));
}

result = result.Where(v => wpGroup == null || v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.WPGroup == wpGroup)
               .Where(v => !myDeals || v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.UserPermission.Any(up => up.UserId == userId));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```cs
.Where(v => parameters.sortedList.Count() > 0 ?
 parameters.sortedList.Contains(v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.DealCode) : true)
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ queries don't execute unless you do something that causes enumeration of the resulting IEnumerable, which means you can have a pattern of:

```
var x = collection.Where(...);

if(sometest)
  x = x.Where(..);

var result = x.ToList(); //enumerate, causing evaluation
```

If `sometest` is true then both the Where will apply (AND style; both where predicates would have to result in a true for a collection entity to appear in the result), if `sometest` is false, then only the first Where applies

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extension

```
public static class WhereIfExtension
{
     public static IEnumerable<TCollection> WhereIf<TCollection>(this IEnumerable<TCollection> source,
            bool condition, Func<TCollection, bool> predicate)
     {
            return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
     }

     public static IQueryable<TCollection> WhereIf<TCollection>(this IQueryable<TCollection> source, bool condition,
            Expression<Func<TCollection, bool>> predicate)
     {
         return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
     }
}
```

then

```
Context.Test
  .Where(v => v.Valuation.ValuationPeriod.PeriodName == periodName && parameters.SelectedTemplateIds.Contains(v.TemplateTypeId) && fundBusinessIds.Contains(v.Fund.BusinessId))
  .WhereIf(parameters => parameters.sortedList.Count() > 0, parameters.sortedList.Contains(v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.DealCode))
  .Where(v => wpGroup == null || v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.WPGroup == wpGroup)
  .Where(v => !myDeals || v.Valuation.PortfolioCompany.UserPermission.Any(up => up.UserId == userId))
```